# Explanation for function composition and infix function application(PureScript)

Tags: purescript

This code works

```
findName :: String -> String -> AddressBook -> Boolean
  findName fname lname =  not <<<  null <<< filter findN
   where
     findN :: Entry -> Boolean
     findN entry = entry.firstName == fname && entry.lastName == lname
```

but this does not

```
findName fname lname book =  not <<<  null <<< filter findN book
```

Again this code works

```
findName fname lname book= not $  null $ filter findN book
```

and this does not

```
findName fname lname = not null $ filter findN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, it is because these different examples are equivalent to different placements of parentheses, so that the code is evaluated differently.
`f <<< g`, where `f` and `g` are functions, is equivalent to `\x -> f (g x)`, whereas `f x $ g y` is equivalent to `(f x) (g y)`. 
Whenever you have an infix symbol like `<<<` and no other infix symbols, the expressions to the left and right of the symbol are evaluated first, so your first example is evaluated as

`findName fname lname      = ((not) <<< (null) <<< (filter findN))`,

which with the `book` parameter made explicit is

`findName fname lname book = ((not) <<< (null) <<< (filter findN)) book`,

whereas your second example is evaluated as

`findName fname lname book = (not) <<< (null) <<< (filter findN book)`.

`filter findN book` yields a list, but `<<<` requires function arguments. 
For your third and fourth example the problem is similar: If I make the `book` parameter explicit in the 4th example, it would be

`findName fname lname = (not $ null (filter findN)) book`, (where you forgot one `$`).

`not $ null $ ...` requires `...` to be an `AddressBook`, but `filter findN` is a function, not an AddressBook.

Comment: In PureScript, a two argument function is actually a one-argument function that returns another one-argument function, so if I have `add x y = x + y`, I can define `add2 y = add 2` and `add2 5` will be 7. `h = f <<< g` is defined as `h x = f (g x)`, so if I have `h = add2 <<< multiply5`, then `h 3` will be 17. But If I write `h x = add2 <<< multiply5 x` and then try to run `h 3`, then PureScript will first calculate `multiply5 3`, which is 15, so then I have `h x = add2 <<< 15`, which is equal to `h x y = add2 (15 y)`, but `15 y` is not a correct expression.

Comment: Does that answer your question?